# Как получить название любого класса в методе класса2, если метод класса2 вызывается в любом классе

Tags: php, классы

Собственно, есть класс *Logger*, который подключается к множеству других классов в виде атрибута. У класса *Logger* есть метод *Logger::log(string)*.
Могу ли я в методе *Logger::log(text)* получить название класса, из которого был вызван этот метод? Это нужно для логирования класса, в котором был вызван метод лог:

```
public function log(string $text): void
{
    $callingClassName = ???;
    $this->addRecord($callingClassName . ': ' . $text);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php

Comment: Спасибо. Сложно было сформировать вопрос, поэтому не нашел этой страницы.

Comment: Конкретно для класса есть `__CLASS__`

Comment: @u_mulder  это тогда в вызывающем классе надо использовать, и передать как аргумент. Автор хочет в вызванном методе все это узнать

Comment: Ааааа, точно, я чет подумал что метод `log` это метод самого класса, а не логгера

Comment: а вы не думали логгер трейтом подключить?